# How do I configure flash groups on the EOS 70D with Yongnuo YN-622C transceivers?

Tags: canon, flash, wireless-flash, canon-70d, yongnuo

For a while I've been using a **Yongnuo YN-622C** transceiver in combination with a **430 EX II** on my **EOS 70D**. Everything works fine so I decided to buy a second 430 EX II and another pair of YN-622Cs. This also works fine when both speedlites use the same configuration.

Now I want to try different flash settings (for example in terms of flash power) but I can't find a way to activate the group settings in my EOS.

Does anybody have experience with EOS 70D (/60D) in combination with YN-622C? Should there be some "wireless flash" option beside the "optical remote" option? I hope there is no incompatibility.

Comment: Have you seen the "Other YN622C Usewr Guide" written by someone who understands English a little better than the OEM guide included with your flash?   https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B77OmmGIg0gMVFpqNkpBYXBHajA/edit?pli=1

Comment: @ Michael Clark: Thanks for the link. Didn't notice this user guide before. I will check this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you would choose the "Optical Remote" option on the camera's menu to do this, even though you're not actually going to be controlling the flashes optically directly from the camera. This is because the camera sees the YN-622C transmitter as a camera mounted external flash. According to the third party written ["The Other YN622C Use Guide"](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B77OmmGIg0gMVFpqNkpBYXBHajA/edit?pli=1), the newer Canon bodies such as the 5D III, the 1D X, the 6D, the 650D, (and presumably the 70D introduced after this manual was written) will function correctly using the YN-622C when set to "Optical Remote". You would need to use the menus on the flashes themselves when doing the initial setup to designate which flash is in 'Group A', 'Group B', or 'Group C'.

Here's where it gets a little murky. Both of your 430EX II flash units are compatible as optically triggered slaves, but not as optical masters. The instructions linked above seem to be saying that the YN-622C system will still allow you to separate them into groups and control the ratios between them, but some settings will need to be made using the controls on the YN-622C itself instead of using the camera's menu.

Comment: Your answer shows me the right way (accept) and the linked user guide is a real benefit (+1). Thank you very much now all work fine.